# Audio not loading immediately after going on

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

If you go [here](https://snowworthybackground.me90.repl.co/) and immediately press the left-most image, and press the play button, it doesn't play. I tested this on Chrome. It works properly on Firefox.

The replit project has 6 files. 3 are the mp3 files, and the rest is an HTML, JS and CSS file.

Here is the code:

```js
// gerates a img button, which gives a modal with the audio
// WARNING! Make sure the variable name doesn't have spaces, because it will be
// the actual HTML class

var make_audio_img_modal = function (img_file_name, audio_file_name, name){
    // append to img parent div
    var img_parent = document.getElementById("display-img-parent")
    img_parent.innerHTML += `<img src="${img_file_name}" alt="${name}" class="display-img" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('modal-link')[${document.getElementsByClassName('modal-link').length}].click();">`

    // append to modal link div
    var modal_link = document.getElementById("modal-links")
    modal_link.innerHTML += `<p><a class="modal-link" href="#${name}-modal" rel="modal:open"></a></p>`

    // append to modal div
    var modals = document.getElementById("modals")
    modals.innerHTML += `<div id="${name}-modal" class="modal">
    <p style="text-align: center;"><audio controls preload="auto" class="audio" preload="false">
        <source src="${audio_file_name}" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.  
    </audio></p>
  </div>`


    var audio_element = document.createElement("AUDIO")

  audio_element.setAttribute("src",audio_file_name);
    modals.appendChild(audio_element)

    // back to the top
    // window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}

// make display image and audio modal
// gets the job done easily
window.onload = function(){ 

    make_audio_img_modal(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/7e/International_Monetary_Fund_logo.svg/1200px-International_Monetary_Fund_logo.svg.png", 
        "https://snowworthybackground.me90.repl.co/music-1.mp3",
        "1")

    make_audio_img_modal(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/7e/International_Monetary_Fund_logo.svg/1200px-International_Monetary_Fund_logo.svg.png",
        "https://snowworthybackground.me90.repl.co/music-2.mp3",
        "2")


    make_audio_img_modal(
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/7e/International_Monetary_Fund_logo.svg/1200px-International_Monetary_Fund_logo.svg.png",
    "https://snowworthybackground.me90.repl.co/music-3.mp3",
    "3")



}
```

```css
img{
    width: 100px;
}

.display-img{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="script.js"></script>

                    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js">

    </script>

    <!-- jQuery Modal -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js">

    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css">

  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="display-img-parent"></div>
        <div id="modal-links"></div>
        <div id="modals"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

music-1.mp3: https://snowworthybackground.me90.repl.co/music-1.mp3

music-2.mp3: https://snowworthybackground.me90.repl.co/music-2.mp3

music-3.mp3: https://snowworthybackground.me90.repl.co/music-3.mp3

How do I make it so that the audio file loads immediately after I go there?

Comment: did you try setting `autoplay` attribute on audio element? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Comment: That didn't work. Also, I don't want it to autoplay. I want it to be loaded.

Comment: so you want to preload the audio?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by an audio file loading immediately (it seems to take quite a time to load when I tried the first one in an audio tag).